# Not able to grant access to APIs after sussessfully registered in B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have registered one web api (TestAPI) in Azure AD B2C by setting Include web app/api and Allow implicit flow to 'YES', provided APP ID URI and added two new scopes for read and write.(By default user_impersonation scope got added)

Then in my existing Web Application while clicking for API ACCESS, I am not able to find out TEST API which I recently registered, in the Select API dropdown.

Please guide. Did I miss any steps in between.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-web-application?

Comment: for creating application, do you mean to say registering web application. I gave application name, Include webapp/api and Allow implicit to yes, set reply URL to https://jwt.ms for testing purpose. Yes, I refered to  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-web-application

Comment: Is that your existing web application was used the same way to register?

Comment: Jim, I am first time creating this in B2C.

Comment: If you want to grant your web API permissions fro your web app, your web application should be registered with the same way. For more details, please refer to https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi.

Comment: If at all you still facing this issue, Try following. 1. Change Directory to any other directory from top right corner  2. Comeback again to B2C 3. Check now API is visible or not

Comment: @Ramakrishna Please add your comment to the answer, then it can be visible to others. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the answer visible to others, I'm summarizing the answer shared in comment:

1. Change Directory to any other directory from top right corner
2. Comeback again to B2C
3. Check now API is visible or not